# Delphi 10.2.3 Clicking OK from Tools > Options gives Script Error

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I recently upgraded to Delphi 10.2.3 and I'm getting some very strange behavior. Whenever I save changes I have made to the Environment Options I get a weird "Script Error" message.

For example: Click Tools > Options and then click the "OK" button I get the following error:

[image]

The changes seem to take effect but I do not understand why I get this script error.

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening or how I can fix it?
I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Delphi 10.2.3 but that did not help.

Comment: seems permission problem. Try running Delphi as administrator

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Can you provide more specifics?

Comment: Just the link to [the script](http://comapi.embarcadero.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js).

Comment: +Wel - Tried that did not help.
@KenWhite - , Windows 10 Professional, Default Browser Chrome, Anti Virus: Kaspersky (I don't think Kaspersky id Delphi friendly)

Comment: Disabling the Community Toolbar did the trick.http://delphicodemonkey.blogspot.com/2017/01/delphi-101-berlin-pro-tip-renaming.html

Comment: Delphi internally uses IE (e.g. Welcome page). But this is weird. Why would one run a web script when saving local settings. Have you joined e.g. EMBT Customer Experience Program?

Comment: @Victoria, I have not joined the EMBT Customer Experience Program? Have you joined? What benefits do you see from joining?

Comment: No. I haven't. I don't know what's that for. I'm just thinking why the IDE runs a web script when saving locally stored settings.

Comment: @Victoria, the EMBT CEP has been depreciated starting with 10.2.3 :-)
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Customer_Experience_Program

Comment: @Victoria, could be just a coincidence of a timer event or a general refresh sent to the toolbars due to the settings change that triggers the request for the community site.

Comment: @Uwe, I'm not a part of that, so it might be so. I cannot say. It was just a brainstorm idea that it's caused by CEP. I see no reason why would IDE execute a web script when saving settings (or at any time) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the Community Toolbar solved the issue.
I'd like to thank [Uwe Raabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26833/uwe-raabe) for pointing me in the right direction.

I'd like to thank [Warren P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84704/warren-p) for his blog post.
http://delphicodemonkey.blogspot.com/2017/01/delphi-101-berlin-pro-tip-renaming.html